# Part of my website not rendering when pushed to heroku

Tags: html, heroku, create-react-app, local

I have a part of my website (react-app) that wont render when pushed to heroku, but it runs fine locally.
The heroku domain is https://notmicahclark.herokuapp.com/

it uploads successfully to heroku no errors

my repo is https://github.com/Scharite13/NotMicahClark.

the page is the /art page.

the code related to it is the art.js file and the images are in the public, and the object is on art_database.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You've generated your `build` folder once. You've since done changes to your code but haven't generated a new build.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});    
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}`));
```

here you can see that you are only serving the content which is in your build folder. It hasn't changed.

Go into your clients folder and execute `npm build` and move the generated build files into `/build`.